# How to ask my friend to call me

Tags: sentence-construction, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-request

My question is how to ask him to call me

> "Whenever you're free call me once"

Is this the correct way of telling him to call me? If not, what would be the correct sentence?

Comment: What you mean by **once** is not clear.   One time and no more?   Once he has a  free moment?  Immediately, without delay?  "at once"?

Answer (score 1):

You could use either of the sentences bellow (more polite):

> Once free, would you please call me?
>
> Would you mind calling me once/when you get a chance?
>
> Call me when you are free (when you get a chance).

The later sounds more like a command but can still be used depending on the context and how comfortable you are with him.

Comment: He is my friend,right now he is in offfice, I whant suggestion from him how to ask to call me once

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'once'? Do you want him to call you just one time? if so, why is that?